# How to get progressbar position to onclick position?

Tags: c#

I've made a Music Player that When I open a movie,the Progress bar works and moves
but when I click in the progress bar to change location of movie it doesn't work.
please answer me.
(tip:I used Progress bar Instead of track bar) 
here is my code

```
void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{
        bunifuProgressBar2.Value = (int)this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;
}

private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_OpenStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_OpenStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.openState == WMPLib.WMPOpenState.wmposMediaOpen)
    {
        bunifuProgressBar2.MaximumValue = (int)axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration;
        t.Start();
    }      
}
```

Comment: Well, implement the MouseDown event handler.  Using a progressbar as a transport control is very inappropriate, you'll just throw this all away again.

Comment: I'd say: use a progress bar for what it's meant to do: show progress. If you want to *modify the progress* use a Slider. Regarding UI design, you can for example overlay the slider over a progress bar and make the slider visible only on progressbar `IsMouseOver="True"`.